# String-format placeholders for maximum compatibility with python 2.6, 2.7 and 3.x

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-2.6

Which placeholders should I use in conjunction with the `.format()`-method of a string so that it is compatible when being used with 2.6, 2.7 and 3.x (3.2 in my case) of the python interpreter?

I started using the `{:}` placeholder but this wasn't working with 2.6. Now I'm using `{<index-of-format-tuple>}` which seems to work on all the listed versions.

Is there a better one to choose? Performance is not an issue, compatibility is.

Comment: You need to specify the index in various circumstances (e.g. if one argument is used more than once) in versions that support `{}` (the colon is redundant) anyway, so I'd stick with the index.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the manual for string formatting in Python 2.6: https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Everything in there should be supported without an issue.

Personally I generally go for the c-style string formatting: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

In most cases it works just fine and it's more familiar to me. And it still supports fairly advanced formatting:

```
>>> print '%(language)s has %(number)03d quote types.' % \
...       {"language": "Python", "number": 2}
Python has 002 quote types.
```